# How to pass part-of-speech in WordNetLemmatizer?

Tags: pandas, nltk, python-3.7, lemmatization, part-of-speech

I am preprocessing text data. However, I am facing issue with lemmatizing. 
Below is the sample text:

> 'An 18-year-old boy was referred to prosecutors Thursday for allegedly
>   stealing about ¥15 million ($134,300) worth of cryptocurrency last
>   year by hacking a digital currency storage website, police said.',
>   'The case is the first in Japan in which criminal charges have been
>   pursued against a hacker over cryptocurrency losses, the police
>   said.', '\n', 'The boy, from the city of Utsunomiya, Tochigi
>   Prefecture, whose name is being withheld because he is a minor,
>   allegedly stole the money after hacking Monappy, a website where users
>   can keep the virtual currency monacoin, between Aug. 14 and Sept. 1
>   last year.', 'He used software called Tor that makes it difficult to
>   identify who is accessing the system, but the police identified him by
>   analyzing communication records left on the website’s server.', 'The
>   police said the boy has admitted to the allegations, quoting him as
>   saying, “I felt like I’d found a trick no one knows and did it as if I
>   were playing a video game.”', 'He took advantage of a weakness in a
>   feature of the website that enables a user to transfer the currency to
>   another user, knowing that the system would malfunction if transfers
>   were repeated over a short period of time.', 'He repeatedly submitted
>   currency transfer requests to himself, overwhelming the system and
>   allowing him to register more money in his account.', 'About 7,700
>   users were affected and the operator will compensate them.', 'The boy
>   later put the stolen monacoins in an account set up by a different
>   cryptocurrency operator, received payouts in a different
>   cryptocurrency and bought items such as a smartphone, the police
>   said.', 'According to the operator of Monappy, the stolen monacoins
>   were kept using a system with an always-on internet connection, and
>   those kept offline were not stolen.'

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

df = pd.read_csv('All Articles.csv')
df['Articles'] = df['Articles'].str.lower()

stemming = PorterStemmer()
stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
lemma = WordNetLemmatizer()

def identify_tokens(row):
    Articles = row['Articles']
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(Articles)
    token_words = [w for w in tokens if w.isalpha()]
    return token_words


df['words'] = df.apply(identify_tokens, axis=1)


def stem_list(row):
    my_list = row['words']
    stemmed_list = [stemming.stem(word) for word in my_list]
    return (stemmed_list)


df['stemmed_words'] = df.apply(stem_list, axis=1)


def lemma_list(row):
    my_list = row['stemmed_words']
    lemma_list = [lemma.lemmatize(word, pos='v') for word in my_list]
    return (lemma_list)


df['lemma_words'] = df.apply(lemma_list, axis=1)


def remove_stops(row):
    my_list = row['lemma_words']
    meaningful_words = [w for w in my_list if not w in stops]
    return (meaningful_words)


df['stem_meaningful'] = df.apply(remove_stops, axis=1)


def rejoin_words(row):
    my_list = row['stem_meaningful']
    joined_words = (" ".join(my_list))
    return joined_words


df['processed'] = df.apply(rejoin_words, axis=1)
```

As it is clear from the code that I am using pandas. However here I have given sample text.

My problem area is :

```
def lemma_list(row):
    my_list = row['stemmed_words']
    lemma_list = [lemma.lemmatize(word, pos='v') for word in my_list]
    return (lemma_list)

df['lemma_words'] = df.apply(lemma_list, axis=1)
```

Though the code is running without any error lemma function is not working expectedly.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above you are trying to lemmatize words that have been stemmed.  When the lemmatizer runs into a word that it doesn't recognize, it'll simply return that word.  For instance stemming `offline` produces `offlin` and when you run that through the lemmatizer it just gives back the same word, `offlin`.

Your code should be modified to lemmatize `words`, like this...

```
def lemma_list(row):
    my_list = row['words']  # Note: line that is changed
    lemma_list = [lemma.lemmatize(word, pos='v') for word in my_list]
    return (lemma_list)
df['lemma_words'] = df.apply(lemma_list, axis=1)
print('Words: ',  df.ix[0,'words'])
print('Stems: ',  df.ix[0,'stemmed_words'])
print('Lemmas: ', df.ix[0,'lemma_words'])
```

This produces...

```
Words:  ['and', 'those', 'kept', 'offline', 'were', 'not', 'stolen']
Stems:  ['and', 'those', 'kept', 'offlin',  'were', 'not', 'stolen']
Lemmas: ['and', 'those', 'keep', 'offline', 'be',   'not', 'steal']
```

Which is is correct.

Comment: Thanks this is working. But one question, you said in your your earlier post that part-of-speech is also required in the WordNetLemmatizer. But here you didn't use it. I want to know does this code only lemmatizes 'verb' or every part-of-speech like noun, adjective, adverb etc.

Comment: The code above uses `pos='v'` so it's going to apply the verb rules.  I believe the way Wordnet works is that it applies the noun rules by default and if you want it operate on a verb, etc.. you need to tell it the POS type.  That means that you need to run a tagger on the original tokenized text and then pass `n`, `v` or `a` to Wordnet if you want it to work correctly for all words.

Comment: >That means that you need to run a tagger on the original tokenized text and then pass n, v or a to Wordnet if you want it to work correctly for all words. Can you tell how to do that in code?

Comment: Take a look at [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html).  If the tag starts with an `N` pass `n` to the lemmatizer, etc..  You might consider using [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) instead.  It's somewhat easier and more accurate.